# How to update custom tabBarComponent value from tabs in react navigation v3.xx

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

How to update tabBar value from tabs in react navigation v3.xx? I have a custom tab bar component which looks like

[image: tabBar]

I want to update total XXX value from tab screen. Inside my screens I make a call to get balances and on success I want to update the balance but I don't know how.

```
class Veggies extends React.Component {
  timer = null;

  state = {
    balance: 0,
    isLoading: false,
  };

  getBalance = () => {
    this.setState({
      isLoading: true,
    });

    this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        balance: 200,
        isLoading: false,
      });
    }, 2000);
  };

  render = () => {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.state.isLoading ? (
          <Text>Getting balances...</Text>
        ) : (
          <Text>Your balance: {this.state.balance}</Text>
        )}

        <Button onPress={this.getBalance} title="Get balance" />
      </View>
    );
  };
}
```

My custom tab bar component

```
const TabBar = props => {
  const { navigationState, navigation, position } = props;

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Your total is : XXX</Text>
      <View
        style={{
          height: 80,
          backgroundColor: 'seashell',
          flexDirection: 'row',
          justifyContent: 'space-around',
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}>
        {navigationState.routes.map((route, index) => {
          const focusAnim = position.interpolate({
            inputRange: [index - 1, index, index + 1],
            outputRange: [0, 1, 0],
          });
          return (
            <Tab
              focusAnim={focusAnim}
              title={route.routeName}
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate(route.routeName)}
            />
          );
        })}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Here's my navigator

```
const TabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
  {
    Vegetables: {
      screen: Veggies,
    },
    Fruits: {
      screen: Fruits,
    },
  },
  {
    tabBarComponent: TabBar,
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(TabNavigator);
```

I know I can easily achieve this with state management libraries like redux but I don't want to use any state management library.

[Expo snack](https://snack.expo.io/PYY7RA09S)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use state management libraries use events.Add event listener in your TabBar and emit event in your tabs.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button, DeviceEventEmitter } from 'react-native';

class Veggies extends React.Component {
  timer = null;

  state = {
    balance: 0,
    isLoading: false,
  };

  getBalance = () => {
    this.setState({
      isLoading: true,
    });

    this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
      //emit event here
      DeviceEventEmitter.emit('updateBalance', 200);
      this.setState({
        balance: 200,
        isLoading: false,
      });
    }, 2000);
  };

  render = () => {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.state.isLoading ? (
          <Text>Getting balances...</Text>
        ) : (
          <Text>Your balance: {this.state.balance}</Text>
        )}

        <Button onPress={this.getBalance} title="Get balance" />
      </View>
    );
  };
}
```

In your TabBar component add event listener

```
class TabBar extends React.Component {
  state = {
    balance: 0,
  };

  handleEevent = balance => {
    this.setState({
      balance: balance,
    });
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('updateBalance', this.handleEevent);
  };

  componentWillUnmount = () => {
    DeviceEventEmitter.removeListener('updateBalance', this.handleEevent);
  };

  render = () => {
    const { navigationState, navigation, position } = this.props;

    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
        <Text>Your total is : {this.state.balance}</Text>
        <View
          style={{
            height: 80,
            backgroundColor: 'seashell',
            flexDirection: 'row',
            justifyContent: 'space-around',
            alignItems: 'center',
          }}>
          {navigationState.routes.map((route, index) => {
            const focusAnim = position.interpolate({
              inputRange: [index - 1, index, index + 1],
              outputRange: [0, 1, 0],
            });
            return (
              <Tab
                focusAnim={focusAnim}
                title={route.routeName}
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate(route.routeName)}
              />
            );
          })}
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  };
}
```

[Demo](https://snack.expo.io/96zvegWn_?platform=android)